# sql converts character data to abbreviated exponential notation in a GROUP BY query

Tags: sql, type-conversion

I have a table of data which includes a field called "unique_booking_reference". Sample data of this character field is

```
4ed74efa3c36d10000  
4ed74efa3c36d10002  
4ee876ab0a01510040  
4ed74efa3c36d10003  
4ed74efa3c36d10004  
4ed74efa3c36d10005  
4f3151bf9213810560  
4f316fb7bb7f010640  
4f3183462abeb10710  
4f3188774374210730  
4f314faa0b25510550
```

However, it appears to be not as unique as the name suggests, although I am struggling to confirm this, which gives rise to my problem. I have a query

```
SELECT unique_booking_reference, count(*) FROM [Bookings-21_dm]
group by unique_booking_reference
having count(*)>1
```

intended to identify any not-so-unique unique_booking_references. However, the result is displayed in what appears to be abbreviated exponential notation, with the result that I can't tell which unique_booking_references are being returned by the query.

```
5.01E+17
```

I have tried the query in both MySQL and Access (Jet-SQL). I have tried inserting spurious characters ("##") into the middle of each value, and a "%" at the beginning for good measure, so that it can't possibly be interpreted as a numerical value, but both SQLs still return abbreviated exponential notation.

```
unique_booking_reference    Total  
%5.01E+17## 2  
%5.07E+17## 2  
%5.09E+17## 2  
%5.16E+17## 11  
%5.16E+18## 4  
%5.17E+17## 15  
%5.17E+18## 26  
%5.25E+17## 2  
%5.27E+17## 2  
%5.29E+17## 3  
%5.31E+17## 2
```

I have also tried casting the values, with no progress. I have tried creating a small table with just the values given above, that works OK, but doesn't help me figure what is wrong.

Why is SQL interpreting a character field as a numeric one, even after I insert spurious characters?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing your sql that casts to a `varchar` but fails to be interpreted as a `varchar`.

Comment: What type is `unique_booking_reference`?

Comment: have you tried `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), unique_booking_reference) AS UniqueID, COUNT(*) FROM [Bookings-21_dm] GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), unique_booking_reference) HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: what happens if you just do `select unique_booking_reference from [Bookings-21_dm]`? and please the RDBMS you are using!

Comment: RDBMS? I have tried MySQL and Access. unique_booking_reference is varchar(255). Tried the CONVERT, same outcome. A SELECT with no GROUP BY is OK.

Comment: It seems there is some implicit type conversion going on. But if that column really is varchar then this should not happen. Not even MySQL does a conversion like that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e535e/1 Are you sure the grouping/conversion happens on the server side and not some "clever" processing done in MS Access? Have you tried with a "normal" SQL tool?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you looking at the results?

I suspect that you are copying them in Excel (or perhaps Access), because I have seen this problem under those circumstances.  I cannot imagine that SQL Server Management Studio, for instance, would do this conversion.  You can prevent this by putting a non-numeric character at the *beginning* of the string.

Try the following version:

```
SELECT '''' + unique_booking_reference, count(*)
FROM [Bookings-21_dm]
group by unique_booking_reference
having count(*) > 1;
```

This pre-pends a single quote and should prevent any downstream application from converting the value to a number.

Comment: I already added '%' in an attempt to do this. Have tried your proposed solution but no joy.

Comment: @user1280840 . . . Hmmm.  All you say leads to the conclusion that the data is actually stored as the character representation of a number in exponential form.  I suspect the problem is in loading the data, not in retrieving it.

Comment: I think your comments have helped me track down the problem. My data table is an import of a CSV file with about 10000 records. I thought the unique_booking_reference field would enable me to check that I had a one-to-one correspondence between records in the CSV (some of which span multiple lines and have fields containing embedded carriage returns) and the imported records. But if the unique_booking_reference is unique in the originating system, in the course of export to CSV, 60 values are converted to abbreviated exponential form, and lose uniqueness in the process (but I didn't spot them)